# Need to make a regular expression match items with different formats

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression to match several items that follow an '=' sign.  Here's what I have so far.

```
= (\S+)(?=SNMP)
```

The result of that is matches on only 12 items of 14 from the following.

```
Enterprise OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.1.1 Trap Type: Enterprise Specific  Trap Sub-Type: .5  Community/Infosec Context: TRAP, SNMP v1, community public  Uptime: 64593430  Description: Enterprise Specific  PDU Attribute/Value Pair Array:SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.1.0 = "Company"|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.2.0 = "200Sou"|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.3.0 = 22|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.4.0 = "ABC TEST ALARM"|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.5.0 = 1|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.6.0 = 2|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.7.0 = 0|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.8.0 = 0|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.9.0 = 0|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.10.0 = 0|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.11.0 = 0|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.12.0 = ""|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.13.0 = "2014-05-27"|SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1453.2.1.1.1.14.0 = "23:12:25"
```

According to [Regexr](http://regexr.com/38tq8), it's matching everything except the section with a trailing space, and the one not followed by 'SNMP'.  Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `\S` matches any *non-white space* character and you have whitespace in one of your values so it will **fail** to match here; to grab your last match add the end of line anchor `$` inside your *lookahead*.

```
= (.*?)(?=SNMP|$)
```

Regular expression:

```
=               '= '
(               group and capture to \1:
 .*?            any character except \n (0 or more times)
)               end of \1
(?=             look ahead to see if there is:
 SNMP           'SNMP'
 |              OR
 $              before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)               end of look-ahead
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kE1yR9)